# How to fix: className='com.hazelcast.aws.AwsDiscoveryStrategy', discoveryStrategyFactory=null Is it a typo in a strategy classname?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hazelcast

I am trying to set two jvm instances in two seperate aws ec2 instances and configure hazelcast cache mechanism between those jvms, and this is the hazelcast.xml

```xml
    <properties>
        <property name="hazelcast.discovery.enabled">true</property>
    </properties>

    <network>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false"/>
            <tcp-ip enabled="false"/>
            <aws enabled="true">
                <region>us-east-2</region>
                <iam-role>my-ec2-role</iam-role>
<!--                <tag-key>aws:cloudformation:stack-name</tag-key>-->
<!--                <tag-value>EC2ContainerService-test-cluster</tag-value>-->
           </aws>
        </join>
    </network>
```

the pom file

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

However, when I run the runnable jar in the aws instance I am getting the following exception :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.hazelcast.config.InvalidConfigurationException: Invalid
>   configuration
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryService.loadDiscoveryStrategies(DefaultDiscoveryService.java:147)
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryService.(DefaultDiscoveryService.java:57)
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryServiceProvider.newDiscoveryService(DefaultDiscoveryServiceProvider.java:29)
>           at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.createDiscoveryService(Node.java:318)
>           at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.(Node.java:255)
>           at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.createNode(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:161)
>           at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:131)
>           at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:228)
>           at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:207)
>           at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:157)
>           at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:91)
>           at hazelMain.main(hazelMain.java:10) Caused by: com.hazelcast.config.properties.ValidationException: There is no
>   discovery strategy factory to create
>   'DiscoveryStrategyConfig{properties={region=us-east-2,
>   iam-role=my-ec2-role},
>   className='com.hazelcast.aws.AwsDiscoveryStrategy',
>   discoveryStrategyFactory=null}' Is it a typo in a strategy classname?
>   Perhaps you forgot to include implementation on a classpath?
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryService.buildDiscoveryStrategy(DefaultDiscoveryService.java:186)
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryService.loadDiscoveryStrategies(DefaultDiscoveryService.java:141)

From my understanding, when we use `<aws enabled = true>`. It should automatically detect the which strategy factory to be used ?

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you see this message, because you don't have `hazelcast-aws.jar` (or `hazelcast-all.jar`) on the classpath. You need to either package your application together with all dependencies or copy one of the mentioned JARs into your EC2 Instance and start with `java -cp hazelcast-aws.jar` (or `java -cp hazelcast-all.jar`).

Comment: I tried the later method using this command ```java -cp hazelcast-aws-1.0.jar -jar aws-runner-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar ``` after uploading the jar into the ec2 instance, in addition this is my pom build instructions ```                            <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
 </descriptorRefs> ``` using the maven assembly plugin . Still I am getting same issue

Comment: Could you try with the latest hazelcast-aws JAR (version `2.4`)?

Comment: unfortunately, always produce the same result

Comment: that's weird, could you share the link to the GH project? It may easier to reproduce and help you.

Comment: I need to include it in payara 5.193. Can I just do cp hazelcast-3.12.4/lib/hazelcast-all-3.12.4.jar payara5/glassfish/modules/ ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and for me the issue was that I'm using Maven's shade plugin to merge all JAR files into a single JAR.

Because Hazelcast uses the Java services framework to load the discovery strategy factories, then there's a file `META-INF/services/com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.DiscoveryStrategyFactory` in each JAR that describes which factory is available in that JAR.

The shade plugin was merging the JARs by overwrite that file - it looks like that with Hazelcast 3.10 and Hazelcast AWS 2.2, the AWS JAR was winning and so its discovery strategy factor was loading, but when I upgraded to 3.12 and 2.4, the core JAR was winning and the AWS discovery strategy factory was not seen by the Java `ServiceLoader`.

The solution was to configure the [`ServicesResourceTransformer` to merge the services files](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ServicesResourceTransformer) (exactly as in the example linked) and that causes the services file to be merged correctly and the factory to get loaded.